# How to get the Xpath for the "Change" button as seen in the screenshot?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, web, xpath

[image]

This is a webapp application and I'm trying to get the Xpath for the "change" button. I tried the below xpath, but it didn't work.

```
//div[@class='co-payment-card']//button[contains(text(),'Change')]
```

Comment: Why not just right click it and inspect. then copy the xpath directly from the DOM

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm supposed to write relative xpath for best practice :)

Comment: Understood what if you tried something like `//*[contains(text(),'Change')]` Assuming thats the only element on the page with that text. I like this site [https://devhints.io/xpath] to help with xpaths.

Comment: Thanks for your response. There are 2 Change buttons in the same page. So this might not work. :)

Comment: XPath looks OK. Do you capture something with an absolute path ? Some ideas you can try for relative paths : 1. Start from another div. `//div[@class="asda—accordion—new__header"]//button[@type="button"]` 2. Since you have 2 change buttons in the same page, select the first one with: `(//button[contains(.,"Change")])[1]` change the number between the brackets accordingly. 3. The hard way : `//*[name()="button" and contains(.,"Change")][ancestor::*[2][name()="div" and @*[name()="class" and contains(.,"header")]]]`

Comment: @E.Wiest thanks for your response. will try the above xpaths